# How to get the UITableViewCell from the known index (integer) of the array and not from IndexPath?

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexpath

have an array `data` of 50 elements and I display them on a UITable view. I have a button on each UITableViewCell and when I click on that button I highlight the cell by adding a border to it. The data from the highlighted cells are stored in another array `highlightedData`. This `highlightedData` array's length is always `2` because I only want two cells highlighted in the table view. When I select the third cell, I remove the element `highlightedData.remove(at: 1)` and append the new data from the third cell in `highlightedData`. I want to remove the border of the cell when it's data was removed from `highlightedData` array. Is there a way that I can get the cell from table view based on the index of its data in the `data` array? I don't want the cell returned by `indexPath` but by an `integer`.

Here is my code for better understanding:

```
func buttonClicked(_ cell: ExampleTableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        if highlightedData.count == 2 {
                 // here I want to get the cell of the element at the index: Int = data.indexOf([highlightedData[1]])
                 highlightedData.remove(at: 1)
                }
            highlightedData.append(data[indexPath.row])
        if highlightedData.count == 2 {
            print("open a new vc")
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's up to your design but isn't it more logically to remove item at 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

Since inside `cellForRowAt` you should have something like

```
// suppose border for someView
cell.someView.layer.borderWidth = highlightedData.contains(indexPath.row) ? 2 : 0
```

Then only reload the table end of `buttonClicked`  , you can also do

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:highlightedData[1], section: 0)) as? ExampleTableViewCell {
    print(cell)
}
```

but it's not recommended as your current change will remove a border from a cell and adds it to another which suitable by a reload

Answer (score 0):

You could also override the `var isSelected` variable for the `UITableViewCell` and do something like this:

```
// UITableViewCell
override isSelected: Bool {
     didSet {
          layer.borderWidth = isSelected ? 2 : 0
     }
}
```

Then you would use the table view cells `func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` method to select the cells. This will automatically handle the appearance without reloading the whole table view and you have the flexibility of selecting or deselecting cells through one method.

You would use that method in the `buttonClicked` function to select and deselect the correct two cells. Something like this:

```
func buttonClicked() {

     guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
     }

     if highlightedData.count == 2 {       
          highlightedData.remove(at: 0)
          tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:highlightedData[0], section: 0)).setSelected(false, animated: false)
     }

      highlightedData.append(data[indexPath.row])
      tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:highlightedData.last!, section: 0)).setSelected(true, animated: false)

}
```